# How to create the same FormGroup as method returns?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-material

I created form as FormGroup displayed on Mat Dialog.
I am trying to write some unit test to be sure about method returns FormGroup.

Method which is called on button click is:

```
closeDialogAndSendForm(): void {
    this.dialogWindow.close(this.form)
```

}

My unit test looks like (I created form with only one field for test cases):

```
it('should close dialog and return FormGroup', fakeAsync(async () => {
    await selectAnswers();
    let resultFormGroup = createResultFormGroup();
    let spy = spyOn(component.dialogWindow, 'close');
    flush();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    clickOnButton('SUBMIT', fixture);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(resultFormGroup);
}));
```

and in `createResultFormGroup()` I would like to create the same form as can be returned by that method:

```
function createResultFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    let form = new FormGroup({testField: new FormControl(true, Validators.required)});
    return form;
}
```

but I am getting many differences like:

```
Call 0:
  Expected $[0]._onCollectionChange = Function to equal Function.
  Expected $[0].pristine = false to equal true.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField._pendingDirty = true to equal false.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField._onCollectionChange = Function to equal Function.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField.pristine = false to equal true.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField._onDisabledChange.length = 1 to equal 0.
  Unexpected $[0].controls.testField._onDisabledChange[0] = Function in array.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField._rawValidators = [ Function ] to equal Function.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField._composedValidatorFn = Function to equal Function.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField._onChange.length = 1 to equal 0.
  Unexpected $[0].controls.testField._onChange[0] = Function in array.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField.valueChanges.currentObservers = [  ] to equal null.
  Expected $[0].controls.testField.statusChanges.currentObservers = [  ] to equal null.
  Expected $[0].valueChanges.currentObservers = [  ] to equal null.
  Expected $[0].statusChanges.currentObservers = [  ] to equal null.
Error: Expected spy close to have been called with:
```

Can I mock it or I do not know compare only fields names and values?

Answer (score 0):

The code look like it has some differences between the expected FormGroup and the actual FormGroup that is returnd by the method. You can try to compare only the field names and values, or you can create a mock FormGroup object that matchs the expected object.

To create a mock FormGroup object, you try the `FormGroup` constructor with an object that has the same fiehd names and initial values as the expectd object. For example:

```
const expectedFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  testField: new FormControl(true, Validators.required)
});

// Create a mock FormGroup with the same field names and initial values
const mockFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  testField: new FormControl(true, Validators.required)
});

// Compare the mock FormGroup with the actual FormGroup
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockFormGroup);
```

This should help you test the method and make it work.

Comment: How can I compare only fields names? I can not get what to do with 'expectedFormGroup' and 'mockFormGroup' it is giving the same result as in my test